# Sending a put command with Curl on php

Tags: php, curl, put

Given the following shell command:

```
curl -X PUT -d arg1='value1'-d arg2='value2' -d arg3='value3' \
https://api.myurl/1/subscriptions/1234;
```

What is the PHP Curl equivalent?

Comment: Did you check the manual? Did you try something?

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this site: https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

Created this:

```
// Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "arg2='value2'");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "arg1='value1'-d&arg3='value3'");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");


$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```